# What does borax do in and to the washing machine?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, surfactants

1. Does borax actually do anything to make clothes cleaner? If it does ....
2. Does it do something with the detergent to remove more dirt from clothes?
3. Does it make it easier to rinse detergent and dirt out of the clothes?
4. Does it work only if the wash cycle uses hot water?
5. Does it un-dissolve in the cooler rinse cycle water and end up building up in the machine?

Comment: I honestly don't think this is a broad question. It's just a few closely related questions bunched up together. It certainly doesn't make much sense to ask all five questions in five new questions, does it? Thoughts?

Comment: This is just a list of super specific yes/no questions - the correct answer will likely not help anyone. I'd like to see this rewritten - the header question is much better than a list off suggestions and a yes/no question. In addition, a short description of the background of the question and the result of a preliminary investigation (google has lots of suggestions, for example) on the author's part will help attract good answers.